# How much carry weight does "Pocketed" add?

Tags: fallout-4

You have the ability to mod your armor and give it a property of "Pocketed" which adds carry weight but it doesn't specify how much. Does it depend on the type of armor that you mod or what the armor is made of?

Comment: i believe its based on armor piece.  arms seems to add 5 legs 10

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This seems to vary from item to item. From my testing so far, I've concluded the following:

- Arm piece will add +5
- Chest piece will add +10
- Leg piece will add +5

Comment: One thing I might add is that the mod also adds weight to the object, for instance Pocketed on a Girded Leather Chest piece adds .5, for a net gain of 9.5