# Carry weight reduces when entering Power Armor

Tags: fallout-4

So like the title says, my max carry weight gets reduced when I enter my Botherhood of Steel Power Armor. My strength pre-power armor equip is a 7, after I put the power armor on it goes up to a 12.....But my max carry weight actually decrease by a decent amount instead of increasing as it should. My carry weight goes from 480 to 472, THAT'S A WHOLE GUN! Is there some kind of variable that once it hits a threshold it decreases instead of increases?

Comment: are you considering that the power armor weighs more than air?

Comment: @kalina: You don't carry power armor, power armor carries you (at least while you're in it). Your carry weight is supposed to go up when you get in.

Comment: well if nobody has answered this by the time I next play Fallout I will test

Comment: How do you get 15? The armor itself sets your base to 11. Brotherhood armor by default is painted to give +1 str, so usually you would have 12. You can also get +1 from armor misc upgrade. That means you get additional bonuses, but not from gear since gear is cancelled out while in power armor. I'm assuming you didn't use any specific chems or other aid with bonus strength when checking? I guess you could get to 15 if you also had the perk Solar Powered on top of that.

Comment: @DCShannon Yes I am very sure that it displays 15 on the SPECIAL page. I will double check again tonight

Comment: @EJS I will double check again tonight, very sure it displays 15....I was deeply confused by this myself

Comment: @EJS You are right it was a 12 I was running on memory and a 12 and 15 are pretty close lol Either way my carryweight should not decrease. Also my strength is at a 7 without armor

Comment: This should be easy to figure out since your carry weight changes by 8, which is not 10. There are no sources I know of that can make this kind of change, Anyone have any suggestions for what can actually change the carrying capacity by 8?

Comment: I must have made a miscalculation when I was checking if stats could go over 11. I definitely was able to get my strength past 11 in power armor with some buffout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that if you are wearing a lot of "Pocketed" armor pieces before you start using Power Armor, you would be giving up the extra carrying capacity that the Pocketed mod offers (30 total if you have both arms, both legs, and chest pieces "Pocketed"). But the increase in carrying capacity due to the Power Armor strength upgrade should outweigh that. Perhaps the strength boost from Power Armor doesn't affect encumbrance the same way it would if you were to add a SPECIAL point to strength?

Related: [How much carry weight does "Pocketed" add?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242768/how-much-carry-weight-does-pocketed-add)

Comment: I think this is probably the reason why. Any bonuses you got from gear will be ineffective as long as power armor is worn.I've got 10 str without power armor, and 12 str with power armor. My carrying weight increases by exactly 20 when I enter the power armor, so there doesn't seem to be a difference between base strength, bonuses from gear or strength set by power armor.

Comment: I remember someone saying when you enter power armor your strength gets set to 10, but i'm not 100% sure this is correct.  However, any bonuses from your armor (I.E. Pocketed armor) isn't applied.  I don't know if that counts for all bonuses either, but Dan C's answer is correct.  I just think there are still some unknown factors that people need to test for.

Comment: Your base strength is set to 11:) I guess it's because they wan't to make sure that strength increases even if your have maxed out strength.

Comment: I will test this out tonight when I get home.

Comment: The only problem with this answer is that going from 8 strength to 15 strength should be 70 more carry weight. Even if you had 5 pieces of armor all with deep pocketed, that's only an additional 50 meaning you should still gain at least 20 from putting on power armor in this case.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill It is going from 7 to 12....so even if that is -50 from pocketed buffs (which it is) to +50 from strength...it should still remain the same.

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is that the Strength boost from wearing power armor is special (ha) and only affects your melee damage or something.

Comment: @DanC But if that's true, where STR doesn't add carry weight, then he should be losing all his pocket bonuses and get a lot more than -8 to his carry weight.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that all legendary mods on armor will not take affect.

At least for me, before power armor I have 11s 5p 11e 8c 8i 3a and 5l. After entering said x01 power armor my stats become 10s 5p 5e 6c 7i 3a 5l.

As you can see my strength was limited to 10 and all other specials went to my defaults: 5 perception, 5 endurance, and 6 charisma. This is strange considering the armor is still "equipped" when in power armor.

The only conclusion I have is that all legendary add-ons from armor are lost upon entering power armor. This could be due to a few things:

1. A mod that adds the ability to add legendary perks to power armor causing the player armor to be overridden
2. Maybe it technically un-equips all your armor upon entering, even though it still says equipped
3. Maybe it's just a bug that they never noticed